# Storing beer in a 25L plastic container instead of bottles

Tags: plastic, glass

I've been asked to brew for some mates that are heading to a sustainable, no glass, festival and need some advice. The only option I could find that was easy to transport and NOT glass was a 25L water container that has a tap. So...as it won't be sitting around long (4 weeks) do you think I can add the sugar normally needed in bottling straight into the water container, seal the lid and get enough pressure to carbonate or will I be sending them off with crap beer?

I've used these containers to do 2 x ginger beer primary ferments in too and was hoping to store them the same way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about PET (plastic) bottles?

Comment: Just curious, and this may be off-topic: what is non-sustainable about glass? It is 100 % recyclable.

Comment: Glass free festival...bummer really as its making my life far too difficult! :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem you have is with being able to keep pressure in a controlled way. If the only issue what the container you could always use a PET carboy or something similar. There is no way this could be made to handle the amount of pressure a normal beer would be carbonated at; both in the wall of the container and the cap.

My suggestion would therefore be, get a **keg**. If you do not own one, find somebody that could lend it to you and put a picnic tap on it. It do not think the beer would last 4wk with a picnic tap, but neither would it in a plastic jug. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, well that's a shame...is it because plastic leeches oxygen? Its thick plastic with a screw tight lid, I usually use them to brew in so thought I might get away with storing too...